# Another form of partial sum of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-series

I've been struggling to prove that partial sum of Fourier series can be defined in the following form:

$$ S_{n}(f)(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t-x)D_{n}(t)dt, $$ where:

$$ D_{n}(t) = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kt)=\frac{\sin(t(n+\frac{1}{2}))}{2\sin(\frac{t}{2})}.$$ And $f$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function. I've managed to show that $$ S_{n}(f)(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)D_{n}(t-x)dt $$, but I don't know how to use the fact of $f$ being $2\pi$-periodic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $D_n$ is even, so we have 
$$S_{n}(f)(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)D_{n}(t-x)dt=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)D_{n}(x-t)dt$$

Write $s=x-t$, so that $t=x-s$, and 
$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)D_{n}(t-x)dt=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x-\pi}^{x+\pi}f(x-s)D_n(s)ds=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-s)D_n(s)ds.$$

Comment: So we use being $2\pi$-periodic to change the integration interval after substitution $s=x-t$?

Additionally I can't see how to proceed any further. :(

Comment: Yes, and this is about as far as you'll get.  the idea is to show that $S_n(f)$ is the convolution of $f$ and $D_n$, and that is exactly what the last integral in my answer is.

Comment: Isn't convolution defined on interval $[-\inf, \inf]$?

Comment: Convolution on the circle (or equivalently, of $2\pi$-periodic functions) is different from convolution on the reals.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Convolutions_on_groups), for instance.  Also, type `\infty` for $\infty$.